# Symbol for the Dow Jones Industrial Average in Alphavantage.co

Tags: programming, fx, market-data

Is there a way to retrieve EOD and intraday data for the Dow Jones from Alphavantage.co API?

I tried DJI, DJIA, DJA. None worked.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you cannot download data for any of the stock indices via Alphavantage. You have to resort to an ETF for intraday data, eg. DIA is an ETF that tracks the Dow Jones index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is ETF?

Comment: ETF stands for Exchange Traded Fund and is a financial product that holds a portfolio of assets in order to either replicate and/or act as a diversifying vehicle for investors. The DIA is an index-ETF that holds the same assets (and the same proportions) as the Dow Jones Index. Therefore, it seeks to provide investment results that, in general, corresponds to the price and yield performance of the Dow Jones Industrial Average. The original provider of the ETF is State Street and they have information about the ETF on their [website](https://shorturl.at/jmBNP).

Comment: Thank you very much. Are you aware of any API that can provide free EOD data for the Dow Jones?